# Cmake Top level project has two dependent projects, one child is also dependent on the other child

Tags: c++, cmake, .a

I have Project A at the top.

Project A requires library B and library C.

Library B also requires library C by itself.

So, in short.  How can I link libraries B and C up to A by just linking B?
I have it working now by individually linking all the libraries, but I feel like there is redundancy I could get rid of.

This is part of the CMAKE for Project A at the top:

```
find_package(libB REQUIRED)
include_directories(${libB_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libB_LIBRARY})

find_package(libC REQUIRED)
include_directories(${libC_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libC_LIBRARY})
```

But also within libB I have this in its CMAKE:

```
find_package(libC REQUIRED)
include_directories(${libC_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libC_LIBRARY})
```

I feel like there is a better way to do this, please let me know.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `target_include_directories` ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)) to specify include directories for your target instead of specifying them for all targets of the current directory using `include_directories`. Among other things, this gives the ability to provide *visibility specifiers* to your includes dirs, which control whether your include dirs will affect only current target (`PRIVATE`), only those targets which link to your target (`INTERFACE`) or both (`PUBLIC`). The same specifiers are used similarly for `target_link_libraries`.

So, you can use `PUBLIC` to avoid duplicating your lib C includes and libraries, and since it is the default specifier, you can omit it. Then, parts of your CMakeLists may look like this:

In project A CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(libB REQUIRED)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libB_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libB_LIBRARY})
```

In lib B CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(libC REQUIRED)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libC_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${libC_LIBRARY})
```

If you, e.g., want only lib B to link to lib C, but leave public 'inheritance' of include directories, you could change the last line of lib B CMakeLists.txt excerpt:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${libC_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: Okay so I removed `find_package(libC REQUIRED)` and `include_directories(${libC_INCLUDE__DIR})` from Project A. In Lib B I changed `include_directories` to `target_include_directories`. But I still have a problem. When I try to build project A, it says it cannot find headers from libC still.

Comment: @shadow It should work if `${libB_LIBRARY}` of project A CMakeLists.txt contains `${PROJECT_NAME}` of lib B CMakeLists.txt (I expected that they are equal to something like `libB`). How do you define project names and how `libB_LIBRARY` variable is generated?